# Ionic Project Accessing FileTransfer

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use the FileTransfer plugin for Ionic/Cordova.

In my logs, I'm getting this: 
`845752   error    Error: Can't find variable: FileTransfer`

When I run this command in the command line:
`ionic emulate ios -lc`

I do a `ionic build ios` first and then the `ionic emulate` command but I still don't have access to that plugin for some reason.

I'm new to Ionic/Phonegap/Cordova and I'm thinking there is a step I'm missing?

Comment: did you inject your dependencies correctly? did you include all the correct js files in your index.html? can you post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a FileTransfer plugin download and upload example, and it works fine in my iphone6 or simulate, you can have a try. Before you try, you need run "cordova plugin ls" command in your project to make sure you have installed these plugins. (They already export to window, just use it.)

1. com.contraterrene.GapFile 1.1.0 "GapFile"
2. cordova-plugin-file 2.1.0 "File"
3. cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.2.2-dev "File Transfer"

```
    $scope.download = function() {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        //  local save path.
        var fileURL = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + "remotefile";
        //  download url
        var uri = encodeURI("http://remoteserver/remotefile");
        fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            fileURL,
            function(entry) {
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
            },
            false, {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": ""
                }
            });
    };
    $scope.write = function() {
        GapFile.writeFile("text_" + Date.parse(new Date()) + ".txt", "hello, i am a file. send me to server", function(fileUrl) {
            $scope.fileUrl = fileUrl;
            console.log("Create File: " + fileUrl);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + error);
        });
    };

    $scope.upload = function() {
        console.log("Upload File: " + $scope.fileUrl);

        function win(r) {
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        }

        function fail(error) {
            console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
            console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
        }

        var uri = encodeURI("http://your_remote_server/upload.php");

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.mimeType = "text/plain";

        var headers = {
            'from': 'ios-app'
        };
        options.headers = headers;
        var ft = new FileTransfer();

        ft.upload($scope.fileUrl, uri, win, fail, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The cordova file transfer plugin is not supported by browser or emulator. You cannot test it in your browser.You have to run your app in mobile devices to test the cordova plugin. Then you can use chrome remote debugging to test the plugin in browser i.e `chrome://inpect#devices`